# Count number of inner elements of array property (Including repeated values)

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Given I have the following records.

```
[
    {
        "profile": "123",
        "inner": [
            {
                "name": "John"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "profile": "456",
        "inner": [
            {
                "name": "John"
            },
            {
                "name": "John"
            },
            {
                "name": "James"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to get something like:

```
"aggregations": {
    "name": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "John",
                "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
                "key": "James",
                "doc_count": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner using Elasticsearch, and this seems to be a pretty simple operation to do, but I can't find how to achieve this.
If I try a simple *aggs* using *term*, it returns 2 for John, instead of 3.
Example request I'm trying:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "inner.name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I possibly achieve this?
Additional Info: It will be used on Kibana later.
I can change mapping to whatever I want, but AFAIK Kibana doesn't like the "Nested" type. :(

Answer (score 5):

You need to do a `value_count` aggregation, by default `terms` only does a `doc_count`, but the `value_count` aggregation will count the number of times a given field exists.

So, for your purposes:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "inner.name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "inner.name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns:

```json
"aggregations" : {
    "name" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "John",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "total" : {
            "value" : 3
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "James",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "total" : {
            "value" : 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly.
Do you by any chance know how can I achieve this in a Kibana chart as well?

Comment: This seems like a different question. It depends on the visualization and I am not 100% how you want it visualized.

Comment: It would actually be a data table, just to have the count by name in the same dashboard of everything else. And yes, I understand it should be another question. sorry for the confusion.